# Multi-touch screen scroll in iterm2?

Tags: display, iterm2

I use screen in iterm2 with [this screenrc](https://github.com/juanpabloaj/dotfiles/blob/master/.screenrc).

I try use the scroll with two fingers in the touchpad, but it doesn't work. I get this:

[image: ss]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Screen has an internal scroll back buffer. [Here's](http://www.samsarin.com/blog/2007/03/11/gnu-screen-working-with-the-scrollback-buffer/) an introduction on how to use it.

You can also disable it by specifying that your Terminal is not capable of providing the mechanism `screen` uses to do its own buffer. Add something like the following to `~/.screenrc`, creating it if it doesn't exist:

```
termcapinfo xterm-color|xterm|xterms|xs|rxvt ti@:te@
```

You already have it in your `.screenrc`, actually, but it appears you configured iTerm to report a different `TERM` than the `xterm` assumed in that file. You can change it in *iTerm » Preferences » Profiles » (select a profile) » Terminal » Report Terminal Type*.

Comment: with this line I get the same. And xterm is my TERM

Comment: @juanpablo Does it work properly when you remove the `hardstatus` lines from your `.screenrc`? Does it work with an otherwise empty `.screenrc`?

Comment: if I remove the hardstatus or I try with a empty screenrc, I have the same output.

Comment: @juanpablo Odd. Or I misunderstood your question. Could you please explain (by editing the question) what it is you want to achieve, and what happens instead? I'm not sure I understand what's wrong with the screenshot.